# Distribution of number of prime factors of $p^k\pm1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorization, probabilistic-number-theory

What is the behavior of number of prime factors of integers of form $p^k\pm1$ where $p$ is a fixed odd prime or $2$ and $k$ varies over positive integers?

Comment: This highly depends on the factorization of $k$. Indeed, $p^k-1 = \prod_{d \mid k} \phi_d(p)$ and $p^{k}+1 = \prod_{d \mid 2k, \, d \nmid k} \phi_d(p)$ where $\phi_d$ is the $d$th cyclotomic polynomial.